# UIImageView with 2 CALayers for border

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, calayer, caanimation

I have a UIImageView that I am trying to frame with a border, by using `CALayer`

My border really consists of 2 borders...the inner border will be 5 pixels wide and white, and the outer border will be 1 pixel wide and light gray.

I can accomplish the first part easily with:

```
myImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
myImageView.layer.borderColorWidth = 5.0f;
```

But I'm struggling to add an additional 1px gray border around that.

Comment: Maybe you can add this imageView as a subview another larger view, and then the the layer border for the new view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a "background view" as a superView of your `myImageView` the "background view" is  1px larger than your `myImageView` the backgroundColor of "background view" is light gray . Then add your `myImageView` as subView

Comment: This solution would work in most cases.  Though, what makes my case a little different is that I am scaling the imageview down to the image size, so that the borders stay consistent around the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
randomView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8f green:0.8f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
randomView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```